# Pixi.js: precision loss when scaled with WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl, pixi.js

This only happens with WebGL renderer. On the picture you can see simple circles added to a DisplayObjectContainer and the DisplayObjectContainer scaled 8x. Apparently the borders do not match the inside of the circles:

```
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFFFFFF);
graphics.drawCircle(x,y,3);
graphics.endFill();
var doc = new PIXI.DisplayObjectContainer();
doc.addChild(graphics);
stage.addChild(doc);
```

[image: Precision loss]

Can I do anything about this or is this inherent to the Pixi(or WebGL) library?

Comment: Have the same issue. If you change to graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xFFFFFF); then its rendered correctly, so any value up to 2 will render incorrectly.